# Get a particular string after matching a string in regex python

Tags: python, regex

I am new python programming. I have been trying to find some data after matching a string using regex.

For example:

```
str1 = 'ethernet33 20628103568 111111 22222222222 '
```

I am only looking for '20628103568', however with my code, it is printing everything after ethernet33

Here is the code

```
match1 = re.search("(?<=ethernet33\s).*(?<=\s)", str1)
print match1.group()
```

output:

```
20628103568 111111 22222222222
```

expected output:

```
20628103568
```

Any guidance on how to modify the above regex to achieve this is would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You should be using this regex instead:

```
>>> import re

#          to match only the digits with  v
#    your "positive lookbehind assertion" v
>>> match1 = re.search('(?<=^ethernet33\s)\d+', str1)
#                           ^ to just match the pattern at the start of string.
#                           ^ prevents additional traversals
>>> match1.group()
'20628103568'
```

Comment: Beat me to it :). FWIW, just `str1.split()[1]` would do in this case.

Comment: Additionally, matching the start with `^` would save you further traversal: `(?<=^ethernet33\s)\d+`

Comment: @heemayl : correct, thanks! it is more efficient. Added it to the answer too

Comment: Awesome!!.. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think `str1.split()[1]` might help